# Getting this error ! Extra }, or forgotten $. ... \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{{T}_{si}}{{T}_{ai}}}

Tags: math-mode, errors

I am getting this error

> ```
> ! Extra }, or forgotten $. ... \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{{T}_{si}}{{T}_{ai}}}
> ```

for equation

```
\begin{equation}
    SLATAH = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{{T}_{si}}{{T}_{ai}}}
\end{equation}
```

can anybody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last curly brace in

```
\begin{equation} SLATAH = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{{T}{si}}{{T}{ai}}}
```

has no opening `{`. You should remove it.